# Cross Validation LOO Model not running, no errors reported

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

When I run this cross validation leave one out, it does nothing, not even an error message. I can't figure out what I am missing. I'm using the csv from kaggle - https://www.kaggle.com/dileep070/heart-disease-prediction-using-logistic-regression/downloads/heart-disease-prediction-using-logistic-regression.zip/1

```
import csv 
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
from pandas import read_csv
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, 
cross_val_predict
from sklearn import metrics
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

#replace missing values with mean
dataset=read_csv("//Users/crystalfortress/Desktop/CompGenetics
/Final_Project_Comp/framingham.csv")
dataset.fillna(dataset.mean(), inplace=True)
print(dataset.isnull().sum())

X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 15].values

model = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=10, gamma = 0.1)
loo = LeaveOneOut()
scores = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=loo, scoring='accuracy')

print('Accuracy after cross validation:', scores.mean())
predictions = cross_val_predict(model, X, y, cv=loo)
accuracy = metrics.r2_score(y, predictions)
print('Prediction accuracy:', accuracy)
x = metrics.classification_report(y, predictions)
print(x)
cf = metrics.confusion_matrix(y, predictions)
print(cf)
```

Comment: Is your python interpreter stalling or finishing and returning nothing?

Answer (score 0):

I tried running this on my machine, it looks like your code works fine (though I did comment out a lot of unnecessary imports). Leave One Out will take a really long time to train a model (it makes `n` training data sets out of `n` data points [link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#leave-one-out-loo)). So you will have to wait for it to train before you will get your results. Changing `cv=` to a number (default is 3, I believe) will train a model more quickly, and most likely have less variance in the model. Also, add `n_jobs=-1` to your `cross_val_score` call will allow python access to all of your processors. E.g.: `scores = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=loo, scoring='accuracy', n_jobs=-1)`

You can also set the `verbose` parameter in your `cross_val_score` as well to watch the progress (though, heads up, it isn't fast). I believe the highest value is 3 (it doesn't mention it in their online docs), but using a higher value is fine. So the final cross_val_score call would look like:

```
scores = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=loo, scoring='accuracy', n_jobs=-1, verbose=10)
```